# Where does Magic Duels store its deck files?

Tags: steam, magic-duels

I'm looking to try and create a reader to turn Magic Deck Files into decklists. But my first step is to work out where it stores those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the profile information in

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\<userID>\316010\remote`

your Steam path may be different, though.

Some info how to read the profile file can be found [here](http://www.slightlymagic.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=99&t=17931).

Credit is due to christinemax from the Magic Duels subreddit - but I wanted to make this information available here as well.

Comment: Also Kuru-. I will be gilding them shortly.